# How to detect when your RAM is being copied or scanned by a hypervisor

Tags: virtualization, intrusion, virtual-memory

I am working in a Virtual Machine that is on a ESXi server on a remote machine. I am not the only one who has access to the ESXi and others could take memory snapshots of my running VM. Is there a way to detect someone trying to take a snapshot, or reading the entire memory?

Comment: If you don't trust the hypervisor, then don't run your application on that machine. Other VMs shouldn't be able to scan your RAMs though, that would be a serious security bug. You can't reliably prevent/detect the hypervisor from doing so.

Comment: My point is not really to prevent the hypervisor from doing it but just to detect it even if i get false positive. I don't have the choice about where my application is going to run unfortunatly.

Comment: You can't reliably detect it, unless the hypervisor notifies the guest that it is about to dump the memory, the hypervisor will always be able to do a scan without you knowing, as the notification can certainly be disabled by a malicious/hijacked hypervisor. If you don't trust the hypervisor, you just don't run your application there. Or rearchitect your application to not rely on the privacy of the server. This can be done through judicious use of end-to-end client-side encryption or signature (i.e. your server never touches the unencrypted data nor the key to decrypt the data it handles).

Comment: You are talking about some kind of notification from the hypervisor, is there an actual legitimate notification that some hypervisor could send to the VM when taking a memory snapshot? I am not really considering a malicious hypervisor but someone that is using it without in debt knowledge of computer security. The application is as secure as we can but finding about someone trying to hack into it is an additional detection we could use.

Comment: you will have to build the notification system yourself of course, probably the hypervisor could write to an external log before dumping or write a wrapper script rather than calling the hypervisor dump directly. If you are not tied to ESXi, you can also switch to open source hypervisor that you can modify. I'd recommend not to spend too much effort on that, if the attacker is already in deep enough to be able to tell the hypervisor to do a memory dump directly, you are already f**ked up. Build your intrusion detector at a higher level, somewhere defensible rather than here.

Comment: of course I understand, changing the ESXi configuration is not an option for me i am afraid. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The [Blue Pill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Pill_%28software%29) malware was detectable with a timing attack; I wonder if something similar could be done by measuring how much time it takes for a memory read/write operation.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, the RAM scraping operation in question doesn't have to take place during the client's write operation. It could take place during the time the client OS is waiting. The particular attack this poster fears may have a signature, but without studying it, there is no way of knowing.

Comment: @AndréDaniel hum that does sound interesting, maybe if i am sometimes stressing the hardware and benchmarking it, detecting a big loss of performance would mean the Hypervisor is also looking at my RAM? That could lead to false positive, I will try to see how much performances are affected furing a memory snapshot.

Comment: @user3779430: in theory, a smart malicious hypervisor could also alter the guest's perception of time to avoid detection of timing attacks. Granted, doing this effectively requires knowing exactly the guest's detection technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The hypervisor controls everything your VM does. The isolation between your VM and other people's VMs relies on the hypervisor. If the hypervisor maps the memory of your VM for its own use, or if it allows other VMs to map it, your VM won't know about it, because of the same isolation mechanisms that don't allow other VMs to access your VM's resources if the hypervisor is operating as desired.

The RAM being copied may actually be part of the normal operation of the hypervisor, to migrate the VM to different physical hardware (e.g. for load balancing or to substitute out failing or obsolescent hardware).

Note that the situation isn't any better if your service is hosted on a physical machine. What you believe to be a physical machine could be a virtual machine, or a physical machine running malicious firmware. If you run code to manipulate confidential data on somebody else's machine, you have to trust them no matter what type of machine it is.

Comment: I wonder if there are hyper visors that provide this level of auditing

Comment: @makerofthings7 Of course there are, e.g. if the server is running open source hypervisor software that anybody can review and check for backdoors. The problem is, how do you know that the server is really running the hypervisor you think it's running? You can get an attestation from the hardware (e.g. if it has a TPM)… but how do you know that the attestation isn't faked? And how do you know that the hardware is free of backdoors? Whatever you do, there is a root of trust on the server.

Comment: I wonder if there would be a way to detect it, though, by using _FLUSH+FLUSH_-style side-channel attacks.

Comment: @forest Whatever your detection code is, a hypervisor could defeat it by simulating the right timings. You can fool a given hypervisor some of the time, and you can fool some hypervisors all the time, but you can't fool all hypervisors all the time.

Comment: @Gilles Not entirely true. While they could trap RDTSC, they cannot trap a register incrementing loop (which is nearly as accurate), or CLFLUSH. Combining those would allow you to measure which cache lines give you a hit, and tell if something (other than you) has accessed that memory recently. Sure, it'd be woefully inefficient, and it might not scale to gigabytes of memory, but it would not be spoofable by the hypervisor since it cannot trap most unprivileged instructions. VT-x is rather limited in what it can trap to a vmexit, making it impossible for a hypervisor to mitigate FLUSH+FLUSH.

Comment: @forest You're talking about a specific processor technology (a recent x86 processor, I guess). Who says this is how the hypervisor is implemented? Who says that the same side channel will work on the next hardware generation? Who says that the hypervisor has no countermeasures?

Comment: You're right, I was only talking about x86, given that the OP specified ESXi (not like you'll get ESXi to run on SH-3!). But if it is on x86, then my statement still holds true (countermeasures can't be implemented using a hypervisor, etc). Maybe in the future, side-channel attacks are partially mitigated, but the question is about the present, not about the theoretical future.